# What are the differences between contextual embedding and word embedding

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to understand the concept of embedding for the deep learning models.

I understand how employing `word2vec` can address the limitations of using the one-hot vectors.

However, recently I see a plethora of blog posts stating ELMo, BERT, etc. talking about contextual embedding.

How are word embeddings different from contextual embeddings?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Both embedding techniques, traditional **word embedding** (e.g. word2vec, Glove) and **contextual embedding** (e.g. ELMo, BERT), aim to learn a **continuous (vector) representation** for each word in the documents.  Continuous representations can be used in downstream machine learning tasks.

Traditional **word embedding techniques** learn a global word embedding. They first build a global vocabulary using unique words in the documents by ignoring the meaning of words in different context. Then, similar representations are learnt for the words appeared more frequently close each other in the documents. The problem is that in such word representations the words' contextual meaning (the meaning derived from the words' surroundings), is ignored. For example, **only one** representation is learnt for "left" in sentence "I **left** my phone on the **left** side of the table." However, "left" has two different meanings in the sentence, and needs to have two different representations in the embedding space.

On the other hand, **contextual embedding methods** are used to learn  **sequence-level semantics** by considering the sequence of all words in the documents. Thus, such techniques learn **different representations** for **polysemous words**, e.g. "left" in example above, based on their context.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. However, how this embedding can be used with the NMT? How NMT will understand which embedding to use?

Comment: First you need to build the contextual embedding model, then you need to pass your text to the model to get the embedding of  words in the text.  Detailed info can be find in https://medium.com/saarthi-ai/elmo-for-contextual-word-embedding-for-text-classification-24c9693b0045

Comment: here is a popular NMT framework: https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt

I have used word2vec embedding with this NMT.

If I understand correctly, for ELMo/BERT it will have multiple embedding for the same word. How NMT will understand which embedding to use?

Comment: I have not used NMT. I think this may explain how to combine BERT into NMT: https://openreview.net/attachment?id=Hyl7ygStwB&name=original_pdf.

Answer (score 17):

Word embeddings and contextual embeddings are slightly different.

While both word embeddings and contextual embeddings are obtained from the models  using unsupervised learning, there are some differences.

Word embeddings provided by `word2vec` or `fastText` has a vocabulary (dictionary) of words. The elements of this vocabulary (or dictionary) are words and its corresponding word embeddings. Hence, given a word, its embeddings is always the same in whichever sentence it occurs. Here, the pre-trained word embeddings are `static`.

However, contextual embeddings (are generally obtained from the transformer based models). The emeddings are obtained from a model by passing the entire sentence to the pre-trained model. Note that, here there is a vocabulary of words, but the vocabulary will not contain the contextual embeddings. The embeddings generated for each word depends on the other words in a given sentence. (The other words in a given sentence is referred as `context`. The transformer based models work on attention mechanism, and attention is a way to look at the relation between a word with its neighbors). Thus, given a word, it will not have a static embeddings, but the embeddings are dynamically generated from pre-trained (or fine-tuned) model.

For example, consider the two sentences:

1. I will show you a valid point of reference and talk to the point.
2. Where have you placed the point.

Now, the word embeddings from a pre-trained embeddings such as word2vec, the embeddings for the word `'point'` is same for both of its occurrences in example 1 and also the same for the word `'point'` in example 2. (all three occurrences has same embeddings).

While, the embeddings from BERT or ELMO or any such transformer based models, the the two occurrences of the word `'point'` in example 1 will have different embeddings. Also, the word `'point'` occurring in example 2 will have different embeddings than the ones in example 1.